# Cannot resolve type entity i8.CommonModule to symbol

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, angular, typescript

[I'm getting this error in my Angular client has anybody seen this issue before about i8? my node version is 19.1.0 :

```
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.12
@angular/cli                    14.2.12
@schematics/angular             14.2.12
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

[image]

I try updating the ng update but nothing has work so far.

Comment: can you share the result of `ng version` ? This is typically an issue when there is a mismatch angular versions.

Comment: btw angular v14 doesn't not support node19, but only up to node16.